# So I locked myself in my office and went to work

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, sentence-structure, learning

> So I locked myself in my office and went to work so I could share my
> Intention Point techniques for the post-pandemic world.

In the above sentence, does **I locked myself in my office** mean:

1. I have closed my office and went to work.

or

2. I stop all my other work temporarily and went to work.

Which one is the correct meaning?

Comment: If you **lock yourself in** somewhere, you go in that place and while you are in there, you lock the door behind you, so no-one can get in. 'Went to work' here means 'started working hard'.

Comment: Please provide a source for your quote

Answer (score 2):

If you lock yourself into a room, it means you lock everyone else out.

In the context of doing some work, it can have two meanings.

One meaning is you prevented interruptions by not allowing anybody else to enter the room and bother you.

The other meaning is you didn't allow yourself to leave the room until the work was done as a means of ensuring the work got done.

From the context of your example sentence, it's not clear whether the goal was to prevent interruptions or force yourself to get the job done, or both.